# how can solve problem the multiple values in bitbucket?

Tags: git, git-config

how can solve problem the multiple values in bitbucket? 
The message that appeared to me

```
warning: user.email has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change user.email.
```

Comment: git config --global user.name "your name"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-config%5D+multiple+values

Answer (score 1):

Replace multiple values with single one:

```
git config --global --replace-all user.email your@email
```